# Undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass for a property from a joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a quick question.
I have 2 tables: Books and Readers. They are joined like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :reader
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :books
end
```

So, in the database I have one book which has a assigned reader, and in the view I have such line in a block:

```
<td><p><%= book.reader.name %></p></td>
```

But it says there is an error `undefined method name for nil:NilClass`, although if I change it with

```
<td><p><%= book.reader %></p></td>
```

it shows me an address of the `object: Reader:0x007fa60ea72f40`

Please could you advise me what is going on here? As I suppose it should show a Reader's name as a result...

the schema of my model is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150320182921) do

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "author"
    t.integer  "pages"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "reader_id"
 end

  create_table "readers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

end

Comment: Did you check in _console_ ?

Comment: Please note `has_many :book` should be `has_many :books`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

I think you have some books with no reader associated. So when you are trying to access name attribute of a nil reader, it is getting exception.

So it would be nice to rescue the `nil` using [`#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try), `try` returns `nil` when called on `nil`:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <%= book.reader.try(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `try` is designed exactly for cases like this. By relying on the fact that `nil.to_s #=> ""` you can to it like so: `book.reader.try(:name)`. In fact, this code outputs `nil` too, if there's no reader, that may not be obvious.

Comment: oh, yes... Thank you! The problem was resolved with the try( ) method!

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid on this using the use [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method. You probably have some books without *authors*, and that's the reason when you are calling `book.author`, you are getting `nil`, on which when you are calling `name` method. That's causing the `NoMethodError` exception. Try to write it using

```
<%= book.author.try(:name) %>
```

Comment: Thank you! i really had only one of books assigned with an author! the method try( ) resolved my issue.